# Render a select recursively in vue js

Tags: arrays, recursion, vue.js

I have the following `array` in `Vue.js`:

```
 epics: {
        1: {'text' : 'Epic 1', 'value' : 1, 'children' : {
                1: {'text' : 'Subepic 1', 'value' : 4},
                2: {'text' : 'Subepic 2', 'value' : 5},
                3: {'text' : 'Subepic 3', 'value' : 6},
            }
        },
        2: {'text' : 'Epic 2', 'value' : 2},
        3: {'text' : 'Epic 3', 'value' : 3}
    },
```

which can be a `n` level deep `array`.

I want to generate a select based on it, with the children options underneath the parent option(recursively). I have searched everywhere but cannot find an example of how one could do this.
Can you please give me any tips on how to do this ?

Example of wanted generated select:

```
<select>
   <option>Epic 1</option>
   <option>Subepic 1</option>
   <option>Subepic 2</option>
   <option>Subepic 3</option>
   <option>Epic 2</option>
   <option>Epic 3</option>
<select>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `epics` "array" is not actually an array, it's an object. So first, i would change it to be an actual array:

```
epics: [
    {
        text: 'Epic 1', 
        value: 1,
        children:[ 
            {text : 'Subepic 1', value : 4},
            {text : 'Subepic 2', value : 5},
            {text : 'Subepic 3', value : 6},
        ]
    },
    {
        text : 'Epic 2', 
        value : 2
    },
    {
        text : 'Epic 3', 
        value : 3
    }
],
```

Notice the square brackets instead of the curly ones.

Then you can define a computed property that will return a flatten version of you epics array:

```
computed: {
    flatted: function() {
        return this.flat(this.epics);
    }
},

methods: {
    flat(items) {
        var final = []
        var self = this
        items.forEach( function(item) {
            final.push(item)

            if (typeof item.children !== 'undefined') {
                final = final.concat(self.flat(item.children));
            }
        })

        return final;
    }
}
```

The computed property will call the flat method, which will process your array and build a new one with all the children at the top level.

Whenever you change the epics array the computed will update itself and give you a flatten version of it.

In your component you can do a `v-for` on this computed property and it will render the select as you want it:

```
<select>
    <options v-for="item in flatted">{{item.text}}</option>
</select>
```

When working with Vuejs think more about manipulate your data to suit the needs of the component instead of thinking about some crazy logic in your component/view.

Comment: yeah, it works, but I did that server side and sent the array back to vue already flattened, thx for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, however I don't want to flatten the data as I wish to indent the display of the option text a specific amount each level, so that the hierarchy is visually apparent.

I think this can be achieved via a recursive component, but I'm not quite sure how – I tried playing around with [this fiddle](https://jsbin.com/yuluka/edit?html,css,js,output) but couldn't quite get it to work.

Basically, I am looking to achieve the following structure from the nested data:

```
<select>
    <option class="level-0">Epic 1</option>
    <option class="level-1">Subepic 1</option>
    <option class="level-1">Subepic 2</option>
    <option class="level-1">Subepic 3</option>
    <option class="level-0">Epic 2</option>
    <option class="level-0">Epic 3</option>
</select>
```

But it needs to work for an variable amount of nested levels. Any pointers?